# How to automatically remove old Feed items in Drupal 7.x?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

Drupal 7.18, I use Feeds and Feed News modules that creates nodes from imported feed items.
Database has grown too large, and I want to completely remove feed items, older than 4 weeks. I can manually delete all items from Feed by editing specific Feed, use "Delete items" tab, but I want to remove only items older than 4 week, and set items expiration rule. I didn't find a settings to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregator module (in core, but deactivated by default) actually does that: it aggregates feed items but doesn't create new nodes.

If you need to create actual nodes to use during that 4-week period (say, in custom views), maybe you can use Rules module to automatically set `published` state to non-published if `$today - $datepublished > 4 weeks`.

Comment: Aggregator module was disabled, but I use Feeds and Feed News modules to create nodes instead of it. I tried to enable Aggregator, but it will not affect feed items, created with Feeds and Feed News.

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for this myself and am just going to create a view that collects all the nids of articles older than 1 month and pass them to [node_delete_multiple($nids)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_delete_multiple/7)
and put it in the hook_cron() of my custom module so it will run with cron. Below is the code in my hook_cron() function.

```
//remove old articles from site.
$old_articles = views_get_view_result('articles_to_delete');
foreach($old_articles as $article){
  $nids_to_delete[]=$article->nid;
}
$num_articles = count($nids_to_delete);
if($num_articles > 0){
  node_delete_multiple($nids_to_delete);
  watchdog('city_sync', '%num old articles were deleted in cron run.', array('%num' => $num_articles), WATCHDOG_NOTICE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed **Devel** module, it have Devel Generate module, in 'Generate content' menu, we can select generate different content types, and option **Delete all content** in given content type before generating new content. I checked this option and set new node quantity to zero. So Devel Generate module deleted all nodes (Feed items) but create no new ones.

Answer (score 0):

There is patch currently in the works that allows you to manage feed items that are removed from the feed:
https://drupal.org/node/1470530